# Google Managed PGSQL DB migration to DigitalOcean Managed PGSQL DB

Tags: postgresql, migration, pg-restore, google-cloud-sql

We are migrating from Google-Cloud PGSQL managed database to a managed PGSQL server on Digital ocean.

The dilemma we are facing is that both Google and Digital ocean are managed so we have no access to directories so we can't dump then restore. So how would we go about this? Is there a command that copies the data directly from Google-Cloud PGSQL to Digital ocean?

Digital oceans [resources](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/databases/postgresql/how-to/import-databases/) assume we have access to a directory.

Comment: You can use `pg_dump` and `pg_restore`, no need to have access to  directories of managed services. Do install `PostgreSQL` binaries in any  VM's like local machine or EC2, Droplets and from there do as https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/databases/postgresql/how-to/import-databases/

Comment: I was really hoping there was a more efficient way then spinning a new VPS.

Comment: You can create pipe for bump and restore, and to optimize this, you can use `-Fc` and `-j #.` and this is an efficient way to do migrate for managed services since we don't have access to the `directory.` nor `pg_dumpall`.

Answer (score 0):

Install [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/app-pgdump.html) and [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/app-pgrestore.html) or `install` entire `PostgreSQL` [Binaries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/install-procedure.html) on your local machine or `EC2`, Droplet compute.

Create a dump file using `pg_dump` that contains the data to be loaded from GCP PG:

```
pg_dump -Fc -v --host=<IP or hostname> --username=<dbadmin> --dbname=<DB name> -f  dbname.dump
```

Restore the data into the target Database for `PostgreSQL` using `pg_restore` :

After you've created the target database, you can use the pg_restore command and the `-d`, `--dbname` parameter to restore the data into the target database from the dump file.

```
pg_restore -v --no-owner --host==<IP or hostname> --port=<port> --username=< dbadmin > --dbname=<target database name> dbname.dump
```

`--no-owner` parameter causes all objects created during the restore to be owned by the user specified with `--username`. For more information , click on [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/app-pgdump.html).